# Zabuto calendar: How to load data via JSON without Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

my project has the requirement that the calendar data is taken from a JSON variable that is not loaded via Ajax, but is in the HTML source code.

So instead of using the Ajax using this:

```
$(".calendar-container").zabuto_calendar({
                    language: "en",
                    today: true,
                    nav_icon: { 
                        prev: '<i class="icon icon-arrow_left"></i>', 
                        next: '<i class="icon icon-arrow_right"></i>' 
                    },
                    ajax: { 
                        url: "json/calendar.json", 
                        modal: false
                    },

... });
```

I need a solution that takes the event data from this variable:

```
var jsondata = '[{"date": "2014-10-02","eventid": 20,"badge": true, "classname": "event"},    { "date": "2014-10-03", "eventid": 20, "badge": true, "classname": "event" }]';
```

that is within a script tag in the HTML source.

Is there any smart way to do so?

Comment: If it is written in script source, why write as JSON as opposed to an actual javascipt array literal?  You save yourself a parsing step.  That being said, have you made any attempt at implementing this?

Answer (score 3):

In version 1.3 you can now use the data option:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var eventData = [
   {
     "date": "2015-01-01",
     "badge": false,
     "title": "Example 1"
   },
   {
     "date": "2015-01-02",
     "badge": true,
     "title": "Example 2"
   }
];
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({ data: eventData });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Old post, but I've made a custom Zabuto calendar.

It's untested and lot's of features are missing but you should give it a peek:

```
  $("#my-calendar").zabuto_calendar({
    language: "fr",
    year: 2015,
    month: 1,
    show_previous: 1,
    show_next: 2,
    // show_reminder: true,
    // show_today: false,
    // show_days: true,
    // weekstartson: 0,
    // nav_icon: {
    //   prev: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-left"></i>',
    //   next: '<i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i>'
    // },
    callbacks: {
      on_cell_double_clicked: function() {
        return cellDoubleClicked(this);
      },
      on_cell_clicked: function() {
        return cellClicked(this);
      },
      on_nav_clicked: function() {
        return navClicked(this);
      },
      on_event_clicked: function() {
        return eventClicked(this);
      }
    },
    events: {
      local: events_array,
      ajax: {
        url: "" // load ajax json events here...
      }
    },
    legend: [
      {label: "Rendez-vous", type: "appointment"},
      {label: "Evenement A", type: "eventtype2"},
      {label: "Evenement B", type: "eventtype3"},
      {label: "<span class='fa fa-bell-o'></span> Rappel", type: "reminder"}
    ]
  });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/n2gkm4d9/

(try double-click in day wrappers, simple-click on events)

Now with:

- init calendar with local json + ajax data
- call public methods (to add just one event at a time for example)
- add event through a modal (not the modal included in zabuto calendar, I've removed it)
- show a list of events of a day
- ...

It's only few hours of work, there's lot of features to add and things to do to make it stable but it's usable. ;-)

Look carefully to the code... there's much more than the fiddle show actually:

Cheers

Fro